# Hand rolled SOAP request

Tags: soap, wsdl, http-headers

I am trying to construct a hand rolled HTTP request in order to return a response from what I thought was a fairly simple SOAP web service call. However, I am having trouble constructing the request properly, and am not getting the response I expect.

---

#### Applicable `wsdl` statements:

*wsdl Target Namespace:*

```
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"
```

*wsdl Service*

```xml
<wsdl:service name="TrackerService">
  <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ITrackerService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ITrackerService">
    <soap:address location="http://mydomain.com/TrackerServiceSite/wctest2.TrackerService.svc"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

*wsdl Message*

```xml
<wsdl:message name="ITrackerService_GetStub_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetStub" /> 
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ITrackerService_GetStub_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetStubResponse" /> 
</wsdl:message>
```

*wsdl Binding and SOAP Operation*

```xml
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITrackerService" type="tns:ITrackerService">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        .
        . <!—- Omitted for brevity --> 
        .
  <wsdl:operation name="GetStub">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITrackerService/GetStub" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

---

#### EXPECTED Return Response

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
      <GetStubResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <GetStubResult xmlns:a=http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/wctest2 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <a:Password>SOMEPASS</a:Password>
          <a:Username>SOMEUSER</a:Username>
        </GetStubResult>
      </GetStubResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

---

#### HTTP request thus far:

```
POST http://mydomain.com/TrackerServiceSite/wctest2.TrackerService.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 297
Host: mydomain.com

<soap:Envelope
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
       <GetStub xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

#### HTTP Response

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
          The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a 
          ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of 
          either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) 
          or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check 
          that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding 
          (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
      </faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

---

I am pretty sure that I need to include a `soapAction` from the wsdl file somewhere in my request, but I'm not sure where to include it. What else am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place your soap action in the [SOAPAction](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528) HTTP header

Comment: That absolutely did it. I knew it had to be something simple. Thank You @Konstantin